# How to save Flex form data into Word document?

Tags: apache-flex, ms-word

I want to save the contents of my Flex application form into a word document. It has rich formatting, hyperlinks, etc. Is is possible to do this? The output can be either "*.doc" or "*.rtf" file.

Thanks,

Nirmal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get info from the for take it server and make a doc using apis like for java http://poi.apache.org/overview.html